# jQuery - AJAX form double submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I've got this submit handler. When the request is made, I've got the form configured to point to a multi-part resource URL (it refers to an object and a child object, each with specified IDs, as part of the path). Whenever I submit the form, not only does it submit the intended request, it also makes a second request with the ID and name of the child object removed from the request URL.

TL;DR: It makes requests to `/foo/1/bar/2` then `/foo/1`, and I need it to stop making that second request.

I've used the standard `event.preventDefault()` and thrown in `return false` for good measure. Not seen here, but I've also tried `$form.submit(false)` as I'd seen on another SO answer somewhere, but removed it since it looks bad and didn't work anyway.

```
function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(e.target);

    $form.find('[type="submit"], [type="button"]').prop('disabled', true);

    var formData = {
        // data
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.prop('action'),
        method: ($form.find('[name="_method"]').val() || $form.prop('method')),
        data: formData,
        error: function(response, status) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        success: function(response, status) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $form.find('[type="submit"], [type="button"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').on('submit', submitForm);
});
```

I'm sure there's a problem somewhere with the AJAX call since removing it causes the form submission to stop as expected. I suppose it's also possible that the AJAX call itself is actually making two requests, but it makes no sense to me why it would do that. It also seems to happen whether the user presses the enter key or actively clicks the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't looking closely enough at the responses I was getting because I was so hung up on the fact I was seeing two outgoing HTTP requests.

The first request was coming back with a 3xx status code, so jQuery was running the second query to the URL it was being redirected to in the first response.

The service controller I was using was not handling AJAX requests properly, so upon modification of the controller to send a different response to AJAX requests, I am no longer getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you're subscribing to the submit request twice, hence the double triggering of the event.  Try ensuring that you unbind first before binding:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').off('submit').on('submit', submitForm);
});
```

Some people say that you should use unbind/bind together as good practice.  This is the same thing, but using `off` instead of `unbind`.

It could also be that you've included the script twice into your pages... check that too!

Comment: The form only exists as one instance. Properties and fields within the form are updated by other events, but there is only one place where the submit event is handled, and that's documented in the question. I did try chaining it with an `off()` anyway and, as expected, it had no effect. I've also added `console.log('submitted');` to the beginning of the handler and it only appears once per submission.

Comment: Did you check that you haven't accidentally included the script twice into your page? :)

Comment: It's only there once as it was always planned to include the form once as a modal dialog and to simply update its values. The script in question is included along with the dialog's HTML. I've also tried pulling out the query settings parameter and putting them into their own variable and dumping them into the console, and I'm getting only the expected settings values. The problem is definitely with the AJAX call itself.

Comment: Hmm that's very perculiar.